# send newsletter to particular email magento

Tags: magento, templates, newsletter

Hi i have more than **1000** users of my site.I want to send a newsletter to them but before that i want to test it for only one user , is it possible to send it to the particular **cuastomer** for test.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /app/code/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php (or the file that is overriding that model)

Modify the method getSubscribersCollection() around line 126 to:

```
$this->_subscribersCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('newsletter/subscriber_collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_email', 'your-test@email.com')
                ->useQueue($this);
```

The newsletter will be sent only to the 'your-test@email.com' user

You can manually run the newsletter queue by opening www.yoursite.com/index.php/admin/newsletter_queue/sending (you might have to disable the secret key in URLs in the admin panel)

Comment: You should never edit core files. Override a core file, but never advise anyone to edit a core file.